# How to create a permiter UIBezierPath from a layer

Tags: ios, calayer, uibezierpath, cgpath

Is there a way to create a UIBezierPath from an arbitrary layer? The layer could be round and I want to get a path that describes its permitter - in order to add subviews with that shape